# Service call fails when parameters exceed a certain (small) number

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight-4.0

I have a Webservice call in my Silverlight application, which fails when the number of items in the parameter is at about 2500. Anybody knows what is going on?

The argument is declared as an observable collection:

```
var pointIds = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<int>();
```

I call it like this:

```
client.ServiceClient.MarkAllPointAsFavouriteAsync(Settings.Current.User.UserId,pointIds);
```

and the servicecall is defined like this:

```
public void MarkAllPointAsFavourite(Guid userId, List<int> pointIds)
    {
        PointRepository.MarkAllPointAsFavourite(userId, pointIds);
    }
```

Why does it fail when calling with a list of approximately 2500 integers?

The error given is:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at Conwx.Net.Client.Framework.CustomerServiceReference.CustomerServiceClient.CustomerServiceClientChannel.EndMarkAllPointAsFavourite(IAsyncResult result)
   at Conwx.Net.Client.Framework.CustomerServiceReference.CustomerServiceClient.Conwx.Net.Client.Framework.CustomerServiceReference.ICustomerService.EndMarkAllPointAsFavourite(IAsyncResult result)
   at Conwx.Net.Client.Framework.CustomerServiceReference.CustomerServiceClient.OnEndMarkAllPointAsFavourite(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)}
```

Comment: Ok, not a very good answer, but I rewrote the service call so the parameter is no longer a list of integers, but instead a filter which was the basis for selecting the list.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it fail when calling with a list of approximately 2500 integers?

I've found it fails at about 2100 items in a list. This is because it's building a query.

In this case as you're not returning anything you could make the method invokable by changing the definition to:

```
[Invoke]
public void MarkAllPointAsFavourite(Guid userId, List<int> pointIds)
{
    PointRepository.MarkAllPointAsFavourite(userId, pointIds);
}
```

This sidesteps the restriction.

You will have to modify the calling code slightly too.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I simply cannot find anything about the `[Invoke]` attribute(?) anywhere. Could you elaborate on this, or some reference to where I can find out more?